# Combining one entire list with iterations of a second list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple problem. I have two lists and would like to generate tuples of the entirety of list with individual elements from list2. I.e.:

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d]
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

Desired output

```
output_list = [([a,b,c,d],1), ([a,b,c,d],2),([a,b,c,d],3)]
```

Comment: `output_list = [(list1, x) for x in list2]`?

Comment: Though note that that's three references to the same underlying `list1` object - use one of the various ways to copy a list (I like the `copy` module with its shallow and deep copy options because it's explicit what's going on, some people prefer `list1[:]` for concision, and `list(list1)` should work to make a shallow copy as well) if you expect to mutate the contents of the tuples and don't want to mutate them all when you do so.

Comment: Thank you @jrd1! I was definitely overcomplicating things. I had fallen down several itertool rabbit-holes trying to make it work. Thank you for a nice simple answer.

Comment: Don't mention it, @SamNmrGoggaRainman!

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will do:

```
output_list = []

for value in list2:
    tup = (list1, value)
    output_list.append(tup)
```

This works by looping through all the values of `list2` and creating a temporary tuple `tup` which contains the entire list `list1` and the value. It finally `append` the tuple to `output_list`